# Histogram of date differences - Grouped

Tags: r

The other day I asked a question about how to get a histogram of the date differences.  I would like to do the same thing, but for groups and with a box plot, using lattice's bwplot.  Essentially, want 1 image with 5 box plots for each of the 5 different sources I have (I've shown 2 below in the example) -- something like this [image].

I've spent quite some time trying to figure this out, but cannot get it.

The closest I could come up

```
df <- read.csv("~/dates.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"")
a <- aggregate(as.POSIXct(as.character(df$REQUEST_DATE), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), list(SOURCE=df$SOURCE), diff) # not sure if this is right (and I need -diff, but can't do that)
# now what?  I seem to know how to access a$SOURCE, but don't know how to look at the data associated with a$SOURCE.
```

The data (~/dates.csv):

```
"SOURCE","REQUEST_DATE"
"A","09/11/2011 09:28:48"
"A","09/11/2011 09:21:15"
"A","09/11/2011 09:15:42"
"A","09/11/2011 09:12:18"
"D","09/13/2011 09:06:53"
"D","09/13/2011 09:06:18"
"D","09/13/2011 08:56:55"
"D","09/13/2011 08:56:18"
"D","09/13/2011 08:55:43"
"D","09/13/2011 08:39:07"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `plyr` package for the data analysis, and `ggplot2` package for the plot:

Read the data.  Note the use of `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` - this saves lots of hassle converting to `as.character` later:

```
df <- read.csv(textConnection('
"SOURCE","REQUEST_DATE"
"A","09/11/2011 09:28:48"
"A","09/11/2011 09:21:15"
"A","09/11/2011 09:15:42"
"A","09/11/2011 09:12:18"
"D","09/13/2011 09:06:53"
"D","09/13/2011 09:06:18"
"D","09/13/2011 08:56:55"
"D","09/13/2011 08:56:18"
"D","09/13/2011 08:55:43"
"D","09/13/2011 08:39:07"
'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Convert to POSIX date format:

```
df$REQUEST_DATE <- as.POSIXct(df$REQUEST_DATE, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Load `plyr` and use `ddply` to a) group by SOURCE, b) calculate difftime, c) group results into a data.frame, all in one step:

```
library(plyr)
df_diff <- ddply(df, .(SOURCE), summarize, TIME_DIFF=-unclass(diff(REQUEST_DATE)))
df_diff
  SOURCE TIME_DIFF
1      A      7.55
2      A      5.55
3      A      3.40
4      D     35.00
5      D    563.00
6      D     37.00
7      D     35.00
8      D    996.00
```

Load `ggplot2` and plot.  The plot looks a bit rubbish - that's because the sample dataset is tiny.  It will work better with larger datasets, i.e. you will get clear separation between median, range and outliers.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_diff, aes(y=TIME_DIFF, x=SOURCE)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow.  You're crazy fast.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I promise this is my last question for you.  How would I do the same thing for a histogram?  I think I need to see the probabilities of each bin too.  Something like [this](http://learnr.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/chapter03-03_04_r.png), where each section is a SOURCE.

Comment: I think I may have got it:  `ggplot(df_diff, aes(x=TIME_DIFF)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 50) + facet_wrap(~SOURCE, ncol = 2, as.table = FALSE) + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 1800), wise=TRUE)`.  Can you tell me if that's right?

Comment: @RonGarrity That looks like a perfectly sensible analysis. Well done for using `ggplot` to its full potential.